# Adding headers to a REST-API request before leaving the server

Tags: rest, authentication, http-headers, qliksense

Within our company we are making use by Qlik. To authenticate within Qlik I need to provide with AD username and password. This works fine for getting acces from your own machine.

Now we want to show a certain dashboard on our narrowcasting so that the whole company can see this dashboard on the TV screens. We've create a user and a password and I've added the URL which is ready for embedding to the narrowcasting schema. The issue right now is that you get the login screen instead of the dashboard you're supposed to see.

This can be solved by adding the authentication to the request header of the request. But unfortunately our narrowcasting tool doesn't provide this option. This narrowcasting tool is on-premise installed, even Qlik is on-premise installed on one of our virtual machines.

Is there another option to add a header to a rest request from a certain VM towards another VM? Or maybe another trick that we can apply here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case might be easier to setup virtual proxy with JWT authentication.

If you have the JWT VP setup then access Qlik via the specified VP prefix and pass the generated JWT as http header.

In order to generate JWT and set the JWT VP you'll need to have access to Qlik's certificates.

Step-by-step guide how to set JWT VP can be found [here](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Official-Support-Articles/Qlik-Sense-How-to-set-up-JWT-authentication/ta-p/1716226)

P.S. You can even create a "fake" user and generate JWT for this user (instead of using a real user)

Comment: Hi Stefan, your solutions works perfect in Chrome indeed. Thanks for letting me know. Might be that I can use this knowledge in the future :)

The issue however with our narrowcasting is not solved yet. Found out that it's making use of it's own browser with most probably no options to add extensions. It's based on Chromium (?), see more info here: https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/specifications/web-engine-specifications.html#grid-layout-level-1

Any other ideas how to solve my issue?

Comment: Any way you can set the header programmatically? Im not familiar with the SmartTV implementations but there is a section in the documentation mentioning "stateless token-based authentication". So if you can pre-set the JWT token then it might work https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/fundamentals/application-security.html (Authentication section)

Comment: Unfortunately we didn't found a solution inside the narrowcasting tool. We're now going to embed the iFrame in a website and do the authentication in there. After that we take the website URL (we will give the page a GUID or a certain hash so that it's still 'private') and embed that one in the narrowcasting tool. Never the less, thanks for your help!